# Using JS to make certain text appear when a list is empty

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a simple contact list web app and the contacts are written in `li` elements. I have a text in a `p#no-contacts` element that I'm trying to set to `display: block` if the `ul` containing the `li` elements has 0 children, and `display: none` if the `ul` contains 1 or more children. I don't know why it's not working.

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/stqyujhw/

Line 94 in JS:

```js
if (contactList.children.length < 1) {
    noContactsMessage.style.display = "block";
} else if (contactList.children.length >= 1) {
    noContactsMessage.style.display = "none";
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm still new to JS.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the fiddle link mentioned in the question

The piece of code should also be present in the event triggered when deleting and adding the contact.
Example deleting contact should have this statement inside it

```
 function deleteContact(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("delete")) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            e.target.parentElement.remove();
        }
    } else if (e.target.classList.contains("fas")) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        }
    }
    if (contactList.children.length < 1) {
       noContactsMessage.style.display = "block";
    }
// NO CONTACTS MESSAGE IF THERE ARE NO CONTACTS


}
```

and Add function should look like this

```
function addContact(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const nameValue = addForm.querySelector("#name-input").value;
    const numberValue = addForm.querySelector("#number-input").value;
    const li = document.createElement("li");

    const nameSpan = document.createElement("span");
    nameSpan.classList.add("name");
    nameSpan.textContent = nameValue;

    const numberSpan = document.createElement("span");
    numberSpan.classList.add("number");
    numberSpan.textContent = numberValue;

    const deleteButton = document.createElement("span");
    deleteButton.classList.add("delete");
    const delIcon = document.createElement("i");
    delIcon.className = "fas fa-user-minus";
    deleteButton.appendChild(delIcon);

    li.appendChild(nameSpan);
    li.appendChild(numberSpan);
    li.appendChild(deleteButton);
    contactList.appendChild(li);
    if (contactList.children.length >= 1) {
    noContactsMessage.style.display = "none";
 } 
}
```

your logic is not getting called in the event that is the reason the code was not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have mentioned is not getting executed on each deletion or addition of `li`. It's just gets executed only once at the loading time. So move the code to event handler of above actions.